# Дано натуральное число. Найти, сколько раз в нем встречается каждая цифра. с++

Tags: c++

Программирование алгоритмов циклической структуры. с++
помогите пжпж, сделал программу для одной цифры, для всех не умею

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int u = 0;
    char a;
    string b;
    cin >> a; //цифра которая дожна встречатся
    cin >> b;
    for (int i = 0; i < int(b.size()); i++)
    {
        if(b[i]==a)
        {
            u++;
        }
    }
    cout << u;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заводите массив счетчиков из 10 элементов, обнуляете его например `int count[10]{0};`. Далее проходите по числу, и на каждую цифру увеличиваете счетчик по индексу. В итоге - у вас получится массив с количеством каждой цифры. Ещё можно использовать `map<int, int>` - смысл тот же.

Answer (score -1):

Цифр всего 10. Заведите массив на 10 элементов, заполните нулями, затем для каждой цифры из b увеличивайте соответствующий элемент

```
int b;
int digits[10]{};
cin >> b;
while (b)
{
    digits[b%10]++;
    b /= 10;
}
```

Теперь пройдите по digits  и выведите цифры и их счётчики